# Literature about Open World Games, Freedom to Choose

Tags: game-design, software-engineering, game-mechanics, books, open-world

I'm doing a diploma thesis about the development of games with freedom to choose or open world.

Topics will be i.e. development issues in programming and the design itself, mechanics etc.

For that I need literature and lot's of it. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Designing Ethical Dilemmas - Slides and Audio
http://designrampage.blogspot.com/2009/06/designing-ethical-dilemmas-slides-and.html

Interesting Mechanics by Brian Green
http://psychochild.org/?cat=248

Design lessons by Brian Green
http://psychochild.org/?cat=12

Games and storytelling, includes controlled branches - Ruben R. Puentedura, Ph.D
http://hippasus.com/resources/gameandlearn/slides/7_GamesAndStorytelling.pdf

Permanent Death - The Complete Saga (play-through with one life in an open world, no restart)
http://drgamelove.blogspot.com/2009/12/permanent-death-complete-saga.html

Comment: Thx for your respond! I'll look into these the next two weeks. Didn't have time to do it yet, since I was pretty occupied with projects and exercises at university...